# Computing minimum of two lengths in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set for a `div` a `margin-left` in JavaScript in such a way that its value if the minimum between two lengths in different units, e.g. `min(10pt,15vw)`.

There is `Math.min()` that we can use to compare numbers. Is there a similar function for lengths?

Alternatively, is there a way to convert length from one unit to another?

Comment: Min function is already there. You will  have to write a conversion function which will convert this numbers to single unit..

Comment: Comparing pixels to percentages without actually rendering the element might turn complicated. Maybe you can render "shadow" elements in both ways, measure their real length (in pixels), and decide based on that. Or, you can redesign your layout using min-width instead.

Comment: I recommend experimenting with the **Live Demo** that I provided in my answer to gather hands on experience with returning the minimum of two values.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum of two lengths with separate units can be calculated by creating a temporary hidden [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) and using the [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) property to calculate the layout width of the element in pixels (followed by immediate removal of the [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)):

```js
const minimum = (a, b) => {
  const temp = document.createElement('div');
  const size = [];

  temp.style.padding = 0;
  temp.style.border = 0;
  temp.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  temp.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  document.body.appendChild(temp);

  temp.style.width = a;
  size[0] = temp.offsetWidth;
  temp.style.width = b;
  size[1] = temp.offsetWidth;

  temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);

  return Math.min(size[0], size[1]) - size[0] ? b : a;
};

console.log('The minimum width is:', minimum('100px', '100%'));
```

As shown above, you can use `minimum('100px', '100%')` to return the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1vw reflects 1% of the viewport's width, you can convert it to pixels using window.innerWidth:

```
var 1vw = window.innerWidth * 0.01;
```

and comparing that with 15 pixels:

```
Math.min(1vw * 15, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple comparison operators for length comparison like =, <=, >= etc. But only when you have same units. The other part of your questions, you can use a small js library for that, called math.js.
The math.js library comes with support for units. The library does not yet support derived units but that is on the planning.

http://mathjs.org/

Comment: So `if (10pt <= 15vw) {document.getElementById('my-div').style.margin='10pt'}` works?

Comment: Why do you @myfirsttime1 feel like a criminal when there is a votedown in StackOverflow ?

Comment: no, of course not. That is for similar units. You will have to make them in similar units and then compare.